# I've Hit a Major Snag While Writing a Paper on Deriving the Cubic Formula!

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

So I've writing a paper for school on deriving the cubic formula. As of now I have written the cubic formula as a system of two equations in terms of original coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. The system is below:

$$z=\sqrt[3]{\frac{9abc-2b^3-27a^2d}{54a^3}\pm\sqrt{\frac{4ac^3+27a^2d^2-18abcd-b^2c^2+b^3d}{108a^4}}}$$

$$x=z-\frac{\left(\frac{-b^2}{3a^2}+\frac{c}{a}\right)}{3z}-\frac{b}{3a}$$

This system is almost entirely based off the work shown in this article (http://math.sfsu.edu/smith/Documents/Cubic&Quartic.pdf). The article says that "Actually, the equation for $z$ gives three complex cube roots for each of the $+$ and $–$ signs, hence six different formulas for $z$. But when you substitute these in the equation for $y$, at most three different $y$ values will result, and the last equation will thus give at most three distince [sic] roots $x$." The mention of a $y$-value can safely be equated to my $x$-value since I combined the original article's two equations ($y=z-\frac{p}{3z}$ and $x=y-\frac{b}{3a}$ into a single equation). Thus, according to the very article that this equation was formulated from, when using the formula I should get 6 $z$-values, but upon plugging these into my second equation to solve for $x$, I should see only 3 distinct $x$-values.

When I test this, however, with the cubic $-2x^3+3x^2-x+5=0$, which has solutions 1.92, -0.21-1.12$i$, and -0.21+1.12$i$, I get the following:

$$z_1=1.399 \therefore x_1=1.901$$
$$z_2=-0.67+1.16i \therefore x_2=-0.2+1.11i$$
$$z_3=-0.67-1.16i \therefore x_3=-0.2-1.11i$$
$$z_4=0.461 \therefore x_4=1.142$$
$$z_5=-0.23+0.4i \therefore x_5=0.18+0.24i$$
$$z_6=-0.23-0.4i \therefore x_6=0.18-0.24i$$

Note that $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$ all came from using a $+$ sign for the $\pm$ input in the equation for $z$ (the complex solutions came from multiplying the real solution by $e^\frac{2i\pi}{3}$ and $e^\frac{4i\pi}{3}$). Coincidentally (or not) only these 3 $z$-values gave correct (though somewhat off due to lazy rounding) $x$-values. The $z$-values derived by using a $-$ sign for the $\pm$ input ($z_4$, $z_5$, and $z_6$), however, did not yield correct $x$-values. More crucially, the prediction the article made that the 6 $z$-values would collapse into only 3 $x$-values when plugged into the second equation did not come true.

This has left me with really nowhere to go. I cannot possibly justify my paper by simply stating that "you have to only use the $+$ side of the $\pm$ sign when solving for $z$ because it just works that way." I need some justification for this decision. Or possibly I have made some mistakes in my calculations and the article's assertion was, indeed, correct. That's what I'm hoping to learn from you guys! If you have any insight into this problem, any questions for me, or any advice, please reach out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lost $4$:

$$z=\sqrt[3]{\frac{9abc-2b^3-27a^2d}{54a^3}\pm\sqrt{\frac{4ac^3+27a^2d^2-18abcd-b^2c^2+\color{red}{4}b^3d}{108a^4}}}$$

And note: $z^3=w \implies z=\{w^{1/3},-(-1)^{1/3}w^{1/3},(-1)^{2/3}w^{1/3}\}$.

I.e. without exponent:

$z_{1,4}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{9abc-2b^3-27a^2d}{54a^3}\pm\sqrt{\frac{4ac^3+27a^2d^2-18abcd-b^2c^2+\color{red}{4}b^3d}{108a^4}}}$

$z_{2,5}=-(-1)^{1/3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{9abc-2b^3-27a^2d}{54a^3}\pm\sqrt{\frac{4ac^3+27a^2d^2-18abcd-b^2c^2+\color{red}{4}b^3d}{108a^4}}}$

$z_{3,6}=(-1)^{2/3}\sqrt[3]{\frac{9abc-2b^3-27a^2d}{54a^3}\pm\sqrt{\frac{4ac^3+27a^2d^2-18abcd-b^2c^2+\color{red}{4}b^3d}{108a^4}}}$

Comment: Yep, this was it. Somehow in both of the equations I used to test this formula, this 4 had barely any impact on the $+$ side of things (so little that I attributed it to rounding errors) but a major impact on the $-$ side of it. Adding this 4 has fixed all that. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 5):

The formula for $x$ and $z$ in the link is

$$ x = z - \frac{p}{3z} - \frac{b}{3a} \qquad \text{and}\qquad z = \sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2} \pm \sqrt{D}}, $$

where $p$, $q$, and $D$ are defined by

$$ p = -\frac{b^2}{3a^2} + \frac{c}{a}, \qquad q = \frac{2b^3}{27a^3} - \frac{bc}{3a^2} + \frac{d}{a}, \qquad\text{and}\qquad D = \frac{q^2}{4} + \frac{p^3}{27}. $$

Applying this to $-2x^3+3x^2-x+5=0$, we obtain

$$ p = -0.25, \qquad q = -2.5, \qquad D \approx 1.56192. $$

Then the six possible values of $z$, denoted by

$$ z_{k,\pm} = e^{2k\pi i/3} \sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2} \pm \sqrt{D}}, $$

are given by

\begin{align*}
z_{0,+} &\approx 1.35717 & \Rightarrow \quad x &\approx 1.91857, \\
z_{1,+} &\approx -0.678583 + 1.17534 i & \Rightarrow \quad x &\approx -0.209285 + 1.12216 i, \\
z_{2,+} &\approx -0.678583 - 1.17534 i & \Rightarrow \quad x &\approx -0.209285 - 1.12216 i, \\
z_{0,-} &\approx 0.0614024 & \Rightarrow \quad x &\approx 1.91857, \\
z_{1,-} &\approx -0.0307012 + 0.0531761 i & \Rightarrow \quad x &\approx -0.209285 - 1.12216 i, \\
z_{2,-} &\approx -0.0307012 - 0.0531761 i & \Rightarrow \quad x &\approx -0.209285 + 1.12216 i. \\
\end{align*}

So I suspect that you made some mistakes. Note that, when computing $z_{k,-}$'s, you have to work with the expression

$$ -\frac{q}{2} - \sqrt{D} $$

where

$$-\frac{q}{2} = 1.25 \qquad\text{and}\qquad \sqrt{D} \approx 1.2497684970810779307.$$

Since these values are very close, their difference leads to the loss of several significant digits. For instance, if we use six digits, then

$$ -\frac{q}{2} - \sqrt{D} \approx (1.25) - (1.24977) = 0.00023, $$

losing four digits in the process! Now, given that you are working under only three significant digits, you will almost certainly lose all the significant digits in this process, ending up with quantities dominated by rounding errors. I strongly suspect that this is the source of your incorrect answer.

Comment: So I was able to replicate your results using your exact method of solving for $p$, $q$, and $D$ using my TI-84+ CE calculator, thus proving that the method the article uses is valid. However, when I then tried to do the same thing but without first solving for $p$, $q$, and $D$, the results were again incorrect. I am fairly certain that it was not a user input error because the results are always valid for the $+$ selection but never valid for the $-$ selection, and I have done this computation with 2 different equations several times each. The same mistake occurred when using WolframAlpha...

Comment: ...but that result was also incorrect, although the result was different. I don't understand what could go wrong with this method when your method worked fine: all I did was substitute in the $q$, $p$, and $D$ values into the $z$ equation. What could've gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You start something of the form:

$z = \sqrt [3] {A \pm \sqrt {A^2+B^3}}\\
x =  z - \frac {B}{z} -\frac {b}{3a}$

Lets choose $z = \sqrt [3] {A + \sqrt {A^2+B^3}}$ and let $\bar z = \sqrt [3] {A - \sqrt {A^2+B^3}} $ represent the conjugate (option with the negative sign).

Then

$z-\frac {B}{z} = z-\frac {B}{\sqrt [3] {A + \sqrt {A^2+B^3}}}\frac {\sqrt [3] {A - \sqrt {A^3+B^2}}}{\sqrt [3] {A - \sqrt {A^2+B^3}}} = z-\frac {B\sqrt [3] {A^2 - {A^2+B^3}}}{\sqrt [3] {A^2 - (A^2+B^3)}} = z + \sqrt [3] {A - \sqrt {A^2+B^3}} = z + \bar z$

And if you transpose $z$ and $\bar z$ you get something identical.

$x = (e^{\frac {2\pi}3i})^k\sqrt[3]{\frac{9abc-2b^3-27a^2d}{54a^3}+\sqrt{\frac{4ac^3+27a^2d^2-18abcd-b^2c^2+b^3d}{108a^4}}} + (e^{\frac {-2\pi}3i})^k\sqrt[3]{\frac{9abc-2b^3-27a^2d}{54a^3}-\sqrt{\frac{4ac^3+27a^2d^2-18abcd-b^2c^2+b^3d}{108a^4}}} - \frac {b}{3a}$

Comment: regarding k, in your work above you talk about multiply one term by $e^{\frac 2\pi i}$ and the other  by $e^{\frac 4\pi i}.$  $k \in {0,1,2}$ does the same thing.  Regarding $\bar z,$ I am using it to represent the quadratic conjugate.  That is if $z = a + \sqrt b$ then $\bar z = a-\sqrt b$

Comment: So you're saying that you evaluate this equation 3 times, once for each $k$-value (0,1,2). But then what is the purpose of having $-2$ in the numerator of the exponent preceding $\bar{z}$ rather than a positive $2$ like before $z$? And to clarify further, essentially what you're doing here is finding 3 $z$-values, then the 3 corresponding $\bar{z}$-values, then plugging these into your equation for $x$, yielding 3 $x$-values?

Comment: When we put $e^{\frac {2\pi}{3} i}$ in the denominator of the second term, it is going to flip signs.   My larger piont, is that we can ignore the $\pm$ sign, and chose one.  The second term will correspond to the conjugate.  And the 3 different values of $k$ will give the 3 different solutions.